# Visual Studio Can't See Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I installed NuGet package manager, but I can no longer seem to access it and I have no idea what the problem is

[image] - This is screen cap from VS showing that it has been installed.  When I go to Tools/Extension Manager I see that I have nuget installed, but it looks like this: [image] with the uninstall and disable buttons grayed out.  There are no menus for Nuget if I right click on References in Solution explorer, or anything in the Tools menu.  I would like to install a new package, but I can't seem to use nuget. I figured I would uninstall it and then reinstall it, but I don't know how to go about that if the option is grayed out.  Any clue on uninstalling and then reinstalling nuget if it's acting up like this?

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio? Did this happen after an update?

Comment: Can you get to the NuGet console for example? (`Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manage Console`). Do you have the `Tools > Library Package Manager >` menus?

Comment: I'm used visual studio for months and didn't realize it quit working until I needed to use it again. It worked fine at one point.

Comment: @CsabaToth No, those are no longer options on the menu.

Comment: What do you see in `Tools > Options > Package Manager`?

Comment: 1. Check if PowerShell works well on your system. 2. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c this talks about some patch for VS2010 updating. BTW, is your VS up to date (VS2010 SP1)? Maybe it's that update issue what the gallery site talks about?

Comment: Hmm, I get this now with VS2010: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581019

Answer (score 0):

You can download NuGet Package Manager from Visual Studio Gallery.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c